# How to use SqLite connection pool in C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection-pooling

The connection string for SqLite can include options for using a connection pool, e.g. (pseudo code)

```
Dim connectionString = "Data Source=" + Path + ";" +
                                    "Version=3;" +
                                    "Pooling=True;" +
                                    "Max Pool Size=100;"
```

I would expect that there is some extra class or factory method for using connection pools, e.g.

```
dim connectionPool = new SqLiteConnectionPool(connectionString)

dim firstConnection = connectionPool.getConnection()
...
firstConnection.dispose()

...
dim secondConnection = connectionPool.getConnection()
```

However, I could not find such a class.

=> **How do I give back a connection to the connection pool**?

=> **How can I reuse a connection that has previously been returned to the pool**?

Searching for "pool" on https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki did not give any results.

a) Do I have to call the constructor for the connection several times?

```
dim firstConnection = new SqLiteConnection(connectionString)
...
firstConnection.dispose()


dim secondConnection = new SqLiteConnection(connectionString)
```

**Passing the connection string several times does not seem to be intuitive for me.**

b) Or would I create the connection only once and somehow wake it up after it has been closed/disposed?

```
dim connection = new SqLiteConnection(connectionString))
using connection 
 ...
end using 

connection.open()
using connection
 ...
end using
```

Comment: Am I having a stroke or is this code a weird mix of C# and VB?

Comment: Might be. :) Just some pseudo code to better explain my question.

Comment: I imagine it works the same way as SQL Server connection pooling.  If pooling is enabled, closing/disposing an open connection returns it to the pool rather than closing the connection to the server.  So you should simply open your connection in a using block to guarantee it is disposed when you've finished, even in the event of an exception.

Comment: So option a) seems to be the way to go. For SQL Server connection pooling here is a doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling If you write it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQLite driver will manage pools for you, however, there is one key point many don't realize when using connections.

**OPEN LATE, CLOSE EARY**

A connection can't be returned to the pool if it's open.  So, you can create the connection, prepare the statements, however, only open the connection immediately before executing the query.